# How to get a current value from jQuery's ajaxSetup

Tags: jquery

I have a page that, at the user's request, opens a dialog box and loads an external file into it using jQuery's load() method.

The external file contains links to scripts (it can work as a standalone page, too) and that's fine, only that jQuery forces those scripts to be loaded (by adding a timestamp) even if they have been loaded already.

I need to tell jQuery to allow caching when it sees these scripts. The answer to a [bug report](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8298)  suggests using

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: true })
```

…which does work, but changes the setting for all future AJAX requests. Is there a way to do something like:

```
// Get current setting - code not valid but is what I want
var defaultCache = $.ajaxSetup("cache");

$.ajaxSetup({cache:true});  // Now set it to what I want

// do stuff…

$.ajaxSetup({cache:defaultCache});  // Set it back to the default
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

you can do this:

```
$.ajaxSetup()['cache']
```

Comment: Of course, it hadn't occurred to me that you can access properties even after a function name. Thanks for the prompt reply!

Comment: For a boolean return, we can use: !!jQuery.ajaxSetup()['cache']

Comment: returns `undefined`. please consider removing or correcting your answer

Answer (score 1):

You could use this:

```
$.ajaxSettings['cache']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Save current global ajax setup
$.cachedAjaxSetup = $.extend(true, {}, $.ajaxSetup());

// change global ajax setup
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers : { "Authorization": 123 }
});

// revert back to saved ajax setup
$.ajaxSetup( $.cachedAjaxSetup );
```

The (annoying) problem is, the object will be merged, so for the above example, the `headers` setting will remain because it didn't exist on the original object.

You can overcome this if you know which properties were added, cache them and remove them manually like so `delete $.ajaxSettings.headers` and then add them back when you need that setting again. dirty, but it works..