# How can I read the default ajax parameters in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

In jQuery I can set ajax default parameters with ajaxSetup like:

```
$.ajaxSetup({'async': false});
```

Is it possible to read them? So that for the example above I knew if async is currently set to `false` or `true`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a current value from jQuery's ajaxSetup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11860354/how-to-get-a-current-value-from-jquerys-ajaxsetup)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this `$.ajaxSetup()['cache']`, but please don't. The use of `ajaxSetup` is not encouraged, this may lead to misbehavior as your application grows bigger, because each Ajax call would depend on the state of your application, which leads to unpredictability.

If you really need default options for ajax, you could try using `$.extend` to merge your current options with the default options returned by some method call.. maybe some object injected through `requireJs` maybe. At least you can debug and see which params are being passed to your request.

Comment: The case is, the application is already big and unpredictable... so I have to use something. Although I finally decided it's better to use `$.ajax()` with explicit async parameter instead of keeping `$.post`-s and manipulating the default behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can do this:

```
var myAjaxSetup= $.ajaxSetup({'async': false});
```

Then

```
if(myAjaxSetup.async){ // dO SOME }
```

But this is only for simple evaluation, if you try to do over $.ajax() call, the "async"  param doesn't exist.

```
var someNice = $.ajax({'async': false});

console.log(someNice.async) //undefined
```