# Does calling jQuery's ajaxSetup with no parameters have any side effects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've read the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11860354/how-to-get-a-current-value-from-jquerys-ajaxsetup) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28051215/how-can-i-read-the-default-ajax-parameters-in-jquery?noredirect=1&lq=1) that describe how to read the value of jQuery ajax settings. My question, however, is this:

if I have previously invoked the `ajaxSetup` function with settings, like `$.ajaxSetup({cache: true})`, and then I invoke `$.ajaxSetup()` (with no arguments), are there any side effects to this invocation?

Or more bluntly, **does calling `$.ajaxSetup()` with no arguments do anything** other than return a plain object that contains the settings for ajax?

The answers I've referenced above both call `ajaxSetup` in this way in order to read the value of a setting, and I have been unable to find any official answer on the jQuery docs that indicate what calling `ajaxSetup` with no parameters does, probably because its use is so heavily discouraged.

In my browser, I ran a simple test by loading jQuery, running `$.ajaxSetup({async: false});` followed by `$.ajaxSetup();` and found that the value of async was still unchanged (the default value is true, and so if calling `$.ajaxSetup()` resets the settings to default values, then the value of async should have been changed), but this probably isn't a strong enough evidence to conclude that side effects do not occur when the function is invoked in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does calling $.ajaxSetup() with no arguments do anything other than return a plain object that contains the settings for ajax?

No.

**Example**

```js
// set a new custom url
$.ajaxSetup({
  url: 'CHANGED'
});

// call it again with no params
$.ajaxSetup();

// the url is still the custom url
console.log('url: ' + $.ajaxSetup().url);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Why?**

If we look at the [code for ajaxSetup](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/cd4ad00478fd02dc04043e9eafc70b2e73e05c87/src/ajax.js#L372), we see that, when called with a single parameter, it returns the call:

```
ajaxExtend( jQuery.ajaxSettings, target );
```

where `target` is the single argument you passed into `ajaxSetup()`.

Now, inside [ajaxExtend](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/cd4ad00478fd02dc04043e9eafc70b2e73e05c87/src/ajax.js#L118), we can see that it tries to iterate over that same argument with a `for in` loop.

Relevant code:

```
function ajaxExtend( target, src ) {

    for (var key in src) {
      // here is where target, which in this case is jQuery.ajaxSettings, gets overriden
    }

    return target;
}
```

Since you don't pass anything, basically you are doing

```
function ajaxExtend( target, src ) {

    for (var key in undefined) {
      // this is never reached
    }

    return target;
}
```

which never enters the `for in` loop and returns the current value of `jQuery.ajaxSettings`.

Comment: OP here, wasn't I who downvoted. In fact I find your answer very helpful. Have an upvote.

Comment: glad you found it useful mate